# Tag synonym suggestion: perks -> benefits

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There is one question tagged with "perks":

> [Negotiating Offers (Verbal Offers & General)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/71237/33064)

This tag seems synonymous with "[benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits)" to me. Although there is only one question tagged with "perks", it seems like a tag that could easily reappear if we just retag this one.

To prevent future retagging work, I suggest that the perks --> benefits tag synonym is created.

Comment: I might argue that "benefits" covers the official job benefits, like health insurance and retirement plans, while "perks" covers the non-official things like free coffee and office parties. However, since there's only one question tagged "perks" (and Monica has already done the merge), I think combining the two is fine.

Comment: @DavidK that's a good point.  If, later, people want to ask questions about perks-not-benefits and the synonym is tripping them up, we can remove the synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea.  I've merged "perks" into [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) and created a synonym.